# How to find CStatic (text) bounding rect of actual content?

Tags: mfc, dialog

When I have a [mfc](/questions/tagged/mfc) *CStatic* control, I can read the control's window rect by

```
CStatic textStatic = GetDlgItem(IDC_TEXT_STATIC);
CRect rect;
textStatic.GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(rect);
```

However, this gives me the bounding rect of the control independent from the actual displayed text. If the text is longer than this, then the text is truncated, and if the text is shorter than this, it does not give me the 'right border' of the text.

For some dynamic resizing of dialogs, I would like to find the bounding rect (or at least the width) of the actually drawn text, not the control itself.

How do I get to this (programatically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable)'s answer above got me started, but was missing the bit to select the appropriate font (to deal with system font DPI setting). The following method now does what I need:

```
CRect GetControlTextRect(CWnd *pWnd)
{
    CString text;
    pWnd->GetWindowText(text);

    CDC* pDC = pWnd->GetDC();
    CFont* pFont = pWnd->GetParent()->GetFont();
    pDC->SelectObject( pFont );

    CRect textRect;
    pWnd->GetWindowRect(&textRect);
    pDC->DrawTextEx(text, &textRect, DT_CALCRECT, NULL);
    return textRect;
}
```

Called f.e. like here:

```
CWnd * txtCtrl = GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);    // IDC_STATIC is the resource ID of the control
CRect rect = GetControlTextRect( txtCtrl ); 
ScreenToClient(rect);
```

Or alternatively like:

```
CStatic txtCtrl = GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);    // IDC_STATIC is the resource ID of the control
CRect rect = GetControlTextRect( &txtCtrl ); 
ScreenToClient(rect);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call [CDC::DrawTextEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dfdzwya.aspx) with the `DT_CALCRECT` formatting option (see [DrawTextEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162499.aspx)). An appropriate device context is returned from a call to [CWnd::GetDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71eseab0.aspx):

```
CRect GetTextSize(int ctrlId) {
    CWnd* pControl = GetDlgItem(ctrlId);
    CString text;
    pControl->GetWindowText(text);

    CDC* pDC = pControl->GetDC();
    CRect textRect;
    pDC->DrawTextEx(text, &textRect, DT_CALCRECT, NULL);
    return textRect;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, [CWnd::GetDlgItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d16yhw(v=vs.120).aspx) returns a pointer to a CWnd.  That would make your sample code incorrect.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the code snippet. It was missing a bit to get the proper values for changed system fonts (see my answer below), but it helped to get me started.